# Можно ли выгрузить данные из таблиц 2ух БД?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

В 1ой базе данных prime1 имеется таблица customers, во 2ой базе данных таблица phone. В обеих таблицах есть 1 совпадающий столбец - id_k. Не получается соединить с помощью LEFT JOIN :(

Comment: Это всё в рамках одного инстанса MySQL? указывайте не просто `tablename`, a `databasename.tablename`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM prime1.customers t1
LEFT JOIN prime2.phone t2 ON t1.id_k = t2.id_k
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_k, c.name, p.mobile 
from db1.customers c
left join db2.phone p using (id_k)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin В предложенном решении нет никаких ньюансов, стандартное решение описанное в любом учебнике по SQL. Вы скорее всего начинающий раз спрашиваете, чтобы вам обьяснили простые общедоступные вещи. Поясните, что вам непонятно в этом запросе?

Comment: дело не во [мне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a178576%20%5bmysql%5d%20or%20%5bsql%5d), а в тех, кто будет искать ответ на свой вопрос. и, попав на эту страницу, увидят не ожидаемый (на данном сайте) развёрнутый ответ с пояснениями, а лишь несколько скупых строчек кода. посмотрите, пожалуйста, на [примеры хороших ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa).